# Does using Chakra UI with Next.js 13 server components expose server-side code logic to the client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, chakra-ui

I'm working on a project using Next.js 13 with server components and Chakra UI for styling. My main concern is protecting sensitive server-side code logic from being exposed to the client when using the app/layout feature.

Chakra UI components are client-side only, and I'm not sure how they interact with server components in terms of code exposure. Specifically, I'm wondering if using the "use client" directive in the layout files might expose code logic from other files as well. For example, if my index file has logic (or imports a component with logic) that determines what html or what components are rendered, will that logic be sent to the client as well, or is the client just receiving the html?

Here's an example of my layout file:

```
"use client";

import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { CacheProvider } from "@chakra-ui/next-js";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <CacheProvider>
          <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is my first time creating a server and client-side app, so any clarification on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question one by one:

> Chakra UI components are client-side only, and I'm not sure how they interact with server components in terms of code exposure.

As you correctly mentioned, Chakra UI components are client-side only. To use Chakra UI with server components, you need to convert the server components into client-side components by adding a 'use client' directive at the top of the file. After the conversion, the components become client-side components, and only the client-side logic will be exposed, not the server-side logic.

> Specifically, I'm wondering if using the "use client" directive in the layout files might expose code logic from other files as well.

If you are using a client-side component, only those components will be rendered on the client side. Server-side logic present in other files or components (eg server components) will not be exposed to the client as long as it is properly isolated and not mixed with client-side code. Note in the latest release of next.js (v13.4), components under the app directory are "server components" by default, hence, only those you mark as "use client" are considered client-side components.

> For example, if my index file has logic (or imports a component with logic) that determines what html or what components are rendered, will that logic be sent to the client as well, or is the client just receiving the html?

Any logic in your index file or other components that determines what HTML or components are rendered will not be sent to the client if it's part of server components. The client will only receive the generated HTML content.

In conclusion, as long as you maintain a clear separation between server-side and client-side components, you should not have to worry about exposing sensitive server-side code to the client.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer all these questions so clearly, its much appreciated.

Comment: how come libraries like chakra wont work on server side components? cant it just be "rendered on the server" and then sent to client?

Comment: They don't work because behind the scene they use React hooks. React hooks are only available in the browser (client side.) If you need some UI library that works in a server component (be part of the initial HTML sent to the client) you need to find one that does not rely on React hooks. Like, for example, daisyUI.